# retrieve all data from all columns from an inner join result

Tags: android, sqlite

How do I retrieve the data on all columns from an `INNER JOIN` result?  I use this query:

```
SELECT course.course_title, 
       course.course_body, 
       course. course_image, 
       instructor.instructor_title, 
       instructor.instructor_body, 
       instructor.instructor_photo
FROM  course
INNER JOIN instructor
ON  course.course_instructor1=instructor.instructor_nid
WHERE course_id=4
```

and this is the equivalent variable `COURSE_OUTLINE` that i'll be using to execute

```
String COURSE_OUTLINE = 
        "SELECT " + Qualified.COURSE_TITLE + ", " 
                  + Qualified.COURSE_BODY + ", " 
                  + Qualified.COURSE_IMAGE + ", "
                  + Qualified.INSTRUCTOR_TITLE + ", "
                  + Qualified.INSTRUCTOR_BODY + ", "
                  + Qualified.INSTRUCTOR_IMAGE + ", " +
        "FROM "   + Tables.COURSE_JOIN_INSTRUCTOR +
        "WHERE "  + CourseColumns.COURSE_ID + 
        "=?";
```

In my code,

```
Cursor cur = mSqliteDb.rawQuery(SubQuery.COURSE_OUTLINE, new String[] {position});
```

This gives 1 record.  I know how to retrieve data from a specific column but I'm not sure how to retrieve it from all columns.

this is the code I use to retrieve data from a specific column

```
public String getCourseImage(int position) {
    String image = "";
    String pos = Integer.toString(position);

    Cursor cur = mSqliteDb.rawQuery(SelectQuery.ALL_COURSES, new String[] {pos});
    if (cur != null) {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                image = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CourseColumns.COURSE_IMAGE)); 
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
        cur.close();
    }
    return image;
}
```

My intention is mapping each data in a column to a `View`

Comment: Are you expecting more than one row? In my book there would be one course with `course_id = 4` and that course would have its one main instructor (specified by `course_instructor1`)

Comment: @lc. from the database, No it should only give 1 record.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. Thought the question was you did not know how to get more rows. What code do you use to retrieve data from a specific column, and what have you tried to map it to a View? (Trying to see exactly what you want to do)

Comment: i updated my question. i already have the result from inner join, my next step is getting the **data** from each column of the result from the inner join that i executed.  mapping these data to a subclass of a `View` is simple its just the data i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getColumnNames](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html) gives you an array with all columns... if that's what you're asking. It's kind of hard to tell.

Comment: its the data that i'd like to retrieve from all columns not the column name itself

Comment: But you said you knew how to get the data for a specific column? `for each column in columns getDataForSpecificColumn`?